# Updating Session Array for Shopping Cart in PHP (updating failure)

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables

I already have the data being sent when the "add to cart" button is pressed, also the display of the items added to the cart, however, I am lost when updating the cart data by the product ID.
What I got is a Book for sale. Array has "Book ID" "Book Quantity" "Book Name" and "Book Unit Price".
What currently happens is that it creates new entries everytime the add cart button is pressed, with each instance quantity and total price being incremented, what I need it to be just one instance in there with the updated info for that 1 book.
So instead of

1. Book Number 1 | Quantity: 3 | Unit Price: $1.00 | Total $3.00
   I would get
2. Book Number 1 | Quantity: 1 | Unit Price: $1.00 | Total $1.00
3. Book Number 1 | Quantity: 2 | Unit Price: $1.00 | Total $2.00
4. Book Number 1 | Quantity: 3 | Unit Price: $1.00 | Total $3.00

I am new to using sessions for product display but learning.
Can anyone please help, I am day number 2 without resolution.

ADD TO CART CODE - be mindful that session has started

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['addtocart'])){
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
'book_id' => $_POST['book_id'],
'bookname' => $_POST['book_name'],
'bookprice' => $_POST['book_price'],
'qty' => $_POST['qty']
);
$hide=2;
}
?>
```

html

```
        <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="book_name" value="Unpacking my Shit">
        <input type="hidden" name="book_price" value="9.99">
        <b class="qtyplus" aria-hidden="true">&plus;</b>
        <input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="addto_cart">Add to Cart</input>
```

And the shopping cart listing page

```
<?php
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $cart){
$total += $cart['bookprice'] * $cart['qty'];
$ultra_total += $total;
$b_id = $cart['book_id'];

if($b_id  == "1"){
$total_qty +=  $cart['qty'];
}

?>
    <tr>
   <td  style=""><?php echo $cart['bookname']; ?> <?php echo $cart['book_id']; ?></td>
    <td  style=""> <?php echo $total_qty; ?> </td>
   <td>$<?php echo $cart['bookprice']; ?></td>
   <td>$<?php echo $total; ?></td>
   <td><a href="">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>

   <?php } ?>

   </table>
  <div style="text- 
   align:center;items:center;background:#0881ae;padding:0.4em;width:40%;color:#fff;font- 
  weight:bold;font-size:120%;border-radius:0px 0px 14px 14px;">
   <b>Total: $<?php echo number_format($ultra_total,2); ?></b></div></div>
```

any help appreciated, any documentary, any similar issues, please send, still reading. thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Edit the code you provided:

```php
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['addtocart'])){
$_SESSION['cart'][$_POST['book_id']] = array( // if you have the ID specified, the new element will be inserted only if it does not exist yet, overwrite otherwise
'book_id' => $_POST['book_id'],
'bookname' => $_POST['book_name'],
'bookprice' => $_POST['book_price'],
'qty' => $_POST['qty']
);
$hide=2;
}
?>
```